# UFW ALLOW rules not working and being ignored

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

We're setting up some zero trust environments and are needing to block all incoming and outgoing ports, except for allowing the office IP to go in (for administrative purposes), and port 80 and 443 to go out in order to access websites. Below is my following setup:

Both incoming and outgoing are set to default DENY

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       (main office IP)              
Anywhere                   ALLOW       (backup office IP)             

(certain website IP) 8080  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
(bitbucket IP) 7999        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

The incoming rules are working fine as expected, but the outgoing rules don't seem to be working at all, whenever a website is attempted to be accessed it says, the browser says "No internet" and the connection is blocked by ufw. I have looked at other people's solutions online, including stackoverflow, and none of these seem to have worked.

Generated IP Tables rules:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-output -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d [ip removed]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d [ip removed]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -s [ip removed]/32 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s [ip removed]/32 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -d [ip removed]/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -d [ip removed]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -d [ip removed]/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7999 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -d [ip removed]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 7999 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
This was ocurring as whilst port 80 and 443 was allowed, the computer was able to successfully access those ports but was unable to access port 53 in order to do a DNS lookup for the DNS records the user is trying to access.

So if anyone else has this issue where they only want to provide access to the internet and no other ports, you need to open port 80, 443, and 53.

Comment: 52 or 53? You mention both.

Comment: DNS is port 53.

Comment: yes, 53, sorry, I updated the post and thought I added a comment, but apparently not. Thanks.